# UIView transitionFromView change view heigh

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am using this code to change between 2 `UIView`:

```
UIViewAnimationOptions animationType = UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft;

[UIView transitionFromView:self.playlistTableView toView:self.playerView duration:0.5 options:animationType completion:^(BOOL finished){
     [self.containerView sendSubviewToBack:self.upperView];
     [self.containerView sendSubviewToBack:self.playerView];

     self.isPlaylistVisible = !self.isPlaylistVisible;
     isControlsHidden = NO;
}];
```

And i noticed a strange behavior, that when i made the flip the height of the `self.playerView` loosing 20px and after one second it's increase back to the normal frame size.

I try to change the `animationType` to `UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews` and now when i change between the view this behavior is not occur.
Any idea what can be the issue?

Comment: Check autoresizing. View's autoresizingMask first of all. And autoresizesSubviews property of self.containerView.

Comment: What should i set as autoresizesSubviews?

Comment: autoresizesSubviews = NO. autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
        [self.upperView setHidden:YES];
        [self.playerView setHidden:NO];
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:containerView cache:YES];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [containerView addSubview:self.playerView];
```

For getting reverse case

```
    [self.upperView setHidden:NO];
    [self.playerView setHidden:YES];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:containerView cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [containerView addSubview:self.upperView];
```